# jquery post variables not being being passed to php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

**SOLVED: 
apparently the only thing going wrong was that i forgot to add quotation marks around the parameters in the query. Thanks for the help everyone!**

i'm having the problem that for some reason the variables that should be filled in my php file are empty. I am doing a $.ajax post. Code below.
i already made sure that the data is actually filled when sending by console.log() on the model that data is being filled with.

The logged model:

```
addedTime: Fri Jul 26 2019 11:01:07 GMT+0200{}
customer: "Test"
message: "test"
message_end_datetime: "2019-07-29"
message_start_datetime: "2019-07-27"
```

Controller that is doing the post:

```
$scope.InsertNew = function(){
    var model = {
        "addedTime" : new Date(),
        "customer" : document.getElementById("customer").value,
        "message" : document.getElementById("message").value,
        "message_start_datetime" : document.getElementById("startTime").value,
        "message_end_datetime" : document.getElementById("endTime").value
    };
    console.log(model);
    var dump = $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http/NewMessage.php",
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function () {
        console.log("succes");
}
      });
}
```

Then in NewMessage.php :

```
<?php
include "include.php"; // has the query php file. 
// $addedTime = $input['addedTime'];
$addedTime = $_POST["addedTime"];
$customer = $_POST["customer"];
$message = $_POST["message"];
$message_start_datetime = $_POST["message_start_datetime"];
$message_end_datetime = $_POST["message_end_datetime"];
newMessageQuery($addedTime,$customer,$message,
$message_start_datetime,$message_end_datetime);
```

Finally in the query file:

```
// doenst work
    function  newMessageQuery($addedTime,$customer,$message,$message_start_datetime,$message_end_datetime){
    $recordsQuery = " INSERT into customernews (added_datetime,customer,message,message_start_datetime,message_end_datetime) 
                        values ('2019-07-26',$customer,$message,'2019-07-26','2019-07-26') "; 
        return executeObjectQuery($recordsQuery);  // executes the query  
    }

//works
    function newMessageQuery($addedTime,$customer,$message,$message_start_datetime,$message_end_datetime){
        $recordsQuery = " INSERT into customernews (added_datetime,customer,message,message_start_datetime,message_end_datetime) 
                            values ('2019-07-26','test','testklant','2019-07-26','2019-07-26') "; 
            return executeObjectQuery($recordsQuery);    
        }
```

As seen above i already tested the query by only using default hard coded values and then it works.

However when using one of the parameter values that should be passed on it doesn't work, im not getting any php errors because it does return succes in javascript which leads me to believe the variables are not getting filled in NewMessage.

**Am i doing something wrong when i pass the values with post or is it something else?**

EDIT:
im getting string(0) "" as the response, response below.

```
Request URL: ../http/NewMessage.php
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 10.0.28.167:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 13
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date: Fri, 26 Jul 2019 09:43:15 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=99
Server: Apache/2.4.23 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2h PHP/5.6.28
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.28
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: retail-web-03
Pragma: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36
```

SOLVED: 
apparently the only thing going wrong was that i forgot to add quotation marks around the parameters in the query. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Comment: You are wrong in expecting $_POST to get populated for this kind of request.

Comment: customer  : $("#customer").val()  try this

Comment: @Jack where am i supposed to put that? in the data when doing the post request?

Comment: is your data is not passing is correct? in ajax getElementById is not used

Comment: getElementById.value is done before the ajax request itself, it is being used to fill the model and the model when filled is passed to data within the request.

Comment: it is codeiginter framework?

Comment: in the query that doesn't work you still have to wrap the values in single quote as you do with the hardcoded one. it is `'$customer'` and not `$customer` unless this is an INT type field and $customer returns a numeric value. The same for `$message` that should be `'$message'`

Comment: @LelioFaieta welp i feel like a fool now, that actually solved it!

Answer (score 0):

You are send data in `Body` of the request. `$_POST` method is only for `form-data`, Here the format is `application/json`.

So you need to use `file_get_contents()` instead of `$_POST`. Your code will be like,

```
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE);

$addedTime = $input["addedTime"];
$customer = $input["customer"];
$message = $input["message"];
$message_start_datetime = $input["message_start_datetime"];
$message_end_datetime = $input["message_end_datetime"];
```

Comment: do i need to do anything more other than change the code with what you just posted? Since im still not getting results

Comment: nope, no errors and the post request still returns succes.

Comment: First just put `var_dump($input)` and check you getting the data,

Comment: yeah im getting null

Comment: Alright, put `var_dump($inputJSON )` after `$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');` line. And check what it returns.

Comment: it prints string(0) "", does that mean something is going wrong when doing the post?

Comment: Yeah exacty. So check the request in `developer-tools network` tab, Make sure your json data is exist in the request

Comment: Add this line `dataType: 'json'` after `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"`. And try!

Comment: when adding that i get an error response and the var dump still prints string(0) ""

Comment: Are you getting any error in javascript console? IF not did you check the request ?

Comment: it actually was just a very stupid mistake of mine, i forgot to add quotes around the $message etc in the query itself, apparently the value are being passed correctly.

Comment: Ahh okay. But did your notice? In your request, I saw this `Request Method: GET`